# how does this code work its printing false ? where did i make mistake?

Tags: python

```py
def check_22(num_list):
    for i in range(0, len(num_list)-1):
        if num_list[i] == 2 and num_list[i+1] == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
print(check_22([3,2,5,1,2,1,2,2]))
```

How come the output is `False` when it needs to display `True`?

Comment: Its because you have `return False` inside your loop and that line is activated through the `else:` clause on the first time through the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does right now is as soon as it gets in checks 3 and 2, they are not both 2 so it returns false. What you want for your purpose is:

```
for i in range(0,len(num_list)-1): 
 if num_list[i]==2 and num_list[i+1]==2: 
   return True
return False
```

So it would return false only after checking the whole list and not finding 2 successive 2s.

Answer (score 0):

Do not return False unless you are done the whole loop

```
def check_22(num_list):
    for i in range(0, len(num_list)-1):
        if num_list[i] == 2 and num_list[i+1] == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all indentation is important in python:

```
def check_22(num_list): 
#start writing your code here
   for i in range(0,len(num_list)-1):
         if num_list[i]==2 and num_list[i+1]==2: 
              return True
         else:
              return False
```

At the beginning, the index i is zero, and thus it checks the first and the second items,they are 3 and 2, thus the test is false, and it returns false. that's all. It ends at the very beginning, That's why the answer is false and not true, it will never check the last two 2s.

Comment: This is the same.. the indentation should be constant, it doesn't matter if it's 2 or 4 spaces.

Comment: It is the same, The behaviour of your function is what I've explained, I mean it is its behaviour but,  if you wanted to know how to return true if there is at least one pair (2,2) in an array, you should not return false inside the for, take a look at svfat answer .